# How did Arya and the Hound get into King's Landing so easily?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Arya and the Hound were planning to stride right into King's Landing, but they were briefly stopped by a Northern guard before the duo breezed past him on their way. However, how did they get into the city? At that point, King's Landing was locked down and fortified; the gates and walls were lined with Lannister soldiers prepared for a siege. Tyrion even recruited Davos Seaworth, "the greatest smuggler alive", to sneak his brother Jaime into the city after Tyrion freed him from captivity. Yet somehow, Arya and the Hound - the latter of whom is well known in the realm - were able to penetrate the city's defenses and stroll right into the Red Keep along with the masses seeking refuge.

Comment: Due to the plot (cloaking) armor!

Comment: Did Davos try and smuggle Jaime *in* to the city? If so, he did terribly since Jaime had to resort to trying to waive his golden hand around to get noticed (...which he wasn't).  I thought Davos was asked by Tyrion to smuggle Jaime/Cersei *out* of the city via a dinghy waiting for them?

Comment: @BruceWayne Obviously it was left off camera, but the implication is that Davos *left* the boat in that inlet. Jaime had walked to it through the entire city of King's Landing. Davos wasn't waiting with the boat: he was inside (nonsensically) fighting in the front lines (again). He possibly might've been asked to help Jaime & Cersei if they'd reached the boat, but (a) they didn't and (b) being asked to leave a dinghy is rather a smaller favor than assisting in treasonously helping the enemy queen escape Dany's vengeance. Tyrion should've just asked for the boat itself.

Answer (score 8):

They were somewhat disguised as civilians and probably blended into the crowd. The gates would be shut last minute and only be heavily guarded as we saw for the gates into the Red Keep. It’s likely commoners from the surrounding lands and farmlands were still flocking in for as long as possible to be safe inside the city.

Comment: IIRC, what you describe was specifically shown in the episode.

Comment: @Makyen _”as we saw for the gates into the Red Keep”_ only getting into the Red Keep is shown not getting into King’s Landing itself.

Comment: True. We see two shots of lots of commoners flowing almost freely into King's Landing. The first shot shows the woman and child Arya interacts with later. The second shot is between when we see Arya and the Hound passing the Northern Guard and when we see Arya and the Hound inside King's Landing with troops climbing a stair onto the wall to Arya's right. The next shot is Jaime Lannister entering King's Landing, walking between Golden Company troops exiting the city, just before the gates are closed. The street Arya and the Hound were on is the same street Jamie used entering King's Landing.

Comment: @Makyen That shot is inside King’s Landing already.

Comment: -1 for now, as **they weren't disguised as *anything***. The Hound was patently the Hound, and Arya was (nonsensically, given her training) dressed as herself.

Comment: @lly the Hound was clearly trying to hide his burn marks, Arya less so. But dressing normally is being disguised as commoners. They weren’t wearing armour or anything distinctive, only blending in. What else would they wear?